# VBA Slow and doesn't work with longer sets of data

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I'm trying to figure out why this macro works with smaller lists of keywords but when we put in larger lists it doesn't work AND goes too slowly.

Program works like this: 
Column A is the input: we paste keywords of interest
Column B is output 1: it populates with all the noise words or stop words that aren't of interest from A. (there will be a 2nd sheet where we can create a list of non-interest words like the, is, by, but, etc)
Column C is output 2: it populates with all the special characters from A.

This is what I have...works with smaller not with bigger sets of words. Been stumped for a while.

```
 Option Explicit

 Dim KeywordSearch As Range 
 Dim NoiseWords As Range 
 Dim cell As Range
 Dim NoiseWord As Range 
 Dim i As Long , j As Long 
 Dim NWTable As ListObject 
 Dim NewRow As ListRow 
 Dim SCTable As ListObject

 Sub Highlight()
     Dim s As String
     Dim offset As Integer
     Dim word As String

     Worksheets("Keyword Search").Activate
     Set KeywordSearch = ActiveSheet.Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown))
     Set NWTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
     Set SCTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SC")

     Worksheets("Noise Words").Activate
     Set NoiseWords = ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))

     ' clear table
     On Error Resume Next

     NWTable.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
         Dim r As Range
         Set r = NWTable.Range.Rows(1).Resize(2)
         NWTable.Resize r

     SCTable.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
         Dim t As Range
         Set t = SCTable.Range.Rows(1).Resize(2)
         SCTable.Resize t

     On Error GoTo 0

     For Each cell In KeywordSearch
         s = cell.Value
         offset = 1

         cell.Interior.Color = vbWhite
         cell.Characters.Font.Color = vbBlack

         Do

         'Replace smart quotes
         For j = 1 To Len(s)
             cell.Characters(j, 1).Text = Replace(cell.Characters(j, 1).Text, Chr(147), """")
             cell.Characters(j, 1).Text = Replace(cell.Characters(j, 1).Text, Chr(148), """")

             ' Find the special characters and add to SpecialCharacters list
             If InStr("""!@#$%&'+,.:;<=>?^`{|}~*()/", Mid(s, j, 1)) > 0 Then
                     cell.Characters(j, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                     Set NewRow = SCTable.ListRows.Add
                     NewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1) = Mid(s, j, 1)

             ' Replace with spaces
                     Mid(s, j, 1) = " "
                     End If
           Next

             ' Find the next space
             i = InStr(offset, s, " ")

             ' If no spaces left then go to end
             If i = 0 Then
                     i = Len(s) + 1
             End If

             ' Extract the word
             word = LCase(Mid(s, offset, i - offset))

                ' Capitalize AND OR NOT
                 If word = "and" Or word = "not" Or word = "or" Then
                     For j = 1 To Len(word)
                         cell.Characters(offset + j - 1, 1).Text = UCase(Mid(word, j, 1))
                     Next
                 End If

              ' Special case to capitalize w/
                If word = "w/" And i < Len(s) Then
                     cell.Characters(i - 2, 2).Text = UCase(word)
                End If

             ' Is the word in the NoiseWord list?
             For Each NoiseWord In NoiseWords
                 If NoiseWord.Value = word Then
                 ' Highlight word
                 cell.Characters(offset, i - offset).Font.Color = 5287936

                 ' Add to NWList
                 Set NewRow = NWTable.ListRows.Add
                 NewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1) = word

                 Exit For
             End If
             Next

             offset = i + 1
             Loop Until i > Len(s)
     Next

     With NWTable.Sort
         .SortFields.Clear
         .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Noise Words]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
         .Apply
     End With

     NWTable.Range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

     SCTable.Range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

     Worksheets("Keyword Search").Activate

 End Sub
```

Comment: It's hard to know the exact reason.  But generally speaking, VBA string manipulation and array manipulation is terribly slow.  So the more string changes you make, the slower it gets.  If you need to manipulate huge strings of data, you can do it by using byte arrays and the copy memory windows API.  Alternatively, break your strings up before you work on them.  A 10000 character long string will take longer to manipulate than 10 1000 character strings, even if your doing the same operations to them and concatenating them all at the end, such as replace statements.

Answer (score 2):

Working with the `Characters` collection is pretty slow, so you may be stuck with some level of poor performance.

However, there are likely some points where you can shave off time.

E.g:

```
For j = 1 To Len(s)
    cell.Characters(j, 1).Text = Replace(cell.Characters(j, 1).Text, Chr(147), """")
    cell.Characters(j, 1).Text = Replace(cell.Characters(j, 1).Text, Chr(148), """")
```

You don't need to use the characters collection at all here: since you just cleared all of the font color, there's no need to use the `Characters` approach vs. just replacing via `.Value`

**EDIT**: it might be worth setting a flag within to loop to track whether *any* character-level formatting has been applied, so you can avoid any unneccessary use of `.Characters` and rely instead on `.Value`

---

You can remove this from the loop:

```
 cell.Interior.Color = vbWhite
 cell.Characters.Font.Color = vbBlack
```

and replace with

```
KeywordSearch.Interior.Color = vbWhite
KeywordSearch.Font.Color = vbBlack
```

before the loop

---

This

```
If word = "and" Or word = "not" Or word = "or" Then
    For j = 1 To Len(word)
        cell.Characters(offset + j - 1, 1).Text = UCase(Mid(word, j, 1))
    Next
End If
```

could be faster as:

```
If word = "and" Or word = "not" Or word = "or" Then
    cell.Characters(offset, len(word)).Text = UCase(word)
End If
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for all the suggestions. Using the .value approach helped a bunch. When I tried your last piece of advice I got the following error: run time error 1004" "unable to set the text property of the characters class". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To speed up calculation where you modify values in spreadsheet you need first to disable screen updates and reenable once you finish processing:

Disabling updates:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Reenabling updates:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely with your use of the `Characters` collection.  If you want to colour the different words found, fine, but do it after you manipulate all the string values.

***Side Note***:  The repeated use of ActiveSheet scares me.  Please set this to a variable at the start of the Subroutine and use the variable instead.

```
Dim Sheet as Worksheet
Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
.
Sheet.Range(...
.
Set Sheet = nothing
```

Look into reading/writing the data to a Variant instead of a range. (at least for the text manipulation)  Here's an example of how to load a Range into a variant:

```
Dim vNoiseWords as Variant
vNoiseWords = Sheet.Range("B2", Sheet.Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Value2
```

Writing is just the opposite (but I usually have to transpose the array).

Then, you can go through the **variant array** and identify the text that needs to be coloured in the cell.

***Minimize Any and All Interactions with the Sheet***

...so limit any line that starts with `ActiveSheet.`, `Cell.`, `Range.` and only process it if it needs to be done.

Even `Cell = UCase(Cell)` is a huge waste of time.

Your much better off doing

```
Value = UCase(Cell.Value2)
If Value <> Cell.Value2 then Cell.Value2 = Value
```

***Update***

FYI, It's easy to pin point the slow parts of your code, by adding timestamps in between sections of code.  Here is a simple routine that I use to keep track of time intervals and display the results in the immediate window.

```
Public Sub TimeStamp(Optional Prompt As String, Optional StartTimer As Boolean)
Static s_fTimer As Single, s_fIntervalTimer As Single
Dim fCurrTime As Single
    fCurrTime = Timer
    If StartTimer Then
        s_fTimer = fCurrTime
        s_fIntervalTimer = fCurrTime
    End If
    If Prompt <> vbNullString Then Prompt = " - " & Prompt
    Debug.Print Format((fCurrTime - s_fTimer), "0.000s") & Format((fCurrTime - s_fIntervalTimer), "(0.000s)") & Prompt
    s_fIntervalTimer = fCurrTime
End Sub
```

The first time you call it (or anytime you want to reset the total time counter), you should set the `StartTimer = True` like this:

```
TimeStamp "Start of Program", True
```

After that, just call the routine, with an optional prompt to keep track of the sections of code:

```
TimeStamp "After Smart Quote Loop"

TimeStamp "The End"
```

Then just look at the time intervals, find the largest ones and whittle them down if you don't think that they are reasonable.  You'll find that every interaction with the UI/cells is the hold up, but processing data in the background takes very little time.